# Angular Material - Can't resolve '@angular/material/theming'

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material2

I have followed the [official guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming) and created a `app-theme.scss` with the following content:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';    
@include mat-core();    
$candy-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$candy-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);    
$candy-app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);    
$candy-app-theme: mat-light-theme($candy-app-primary, $candy-app-accent, $candy-app-warn);    
@include angular-material-theme($candy-app-theme);
```

Content of `styles.css`:

```
@import './app-theme.scss';
```

However, I always get the following error during compilation: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/material/theming'`. What must I do to make it work?

Comment: Which version of angular material are you using?

Comment: @Faisal @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.8

Comment: For anybody coming here in 2023, this config is valid up to Angular Material 11. From version 12, the config syntax changed significantly.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Solved:

The Angular Material 2 documentation assumes you are using sass style-sheets by default. This is never clearly communicated or explained. The steps listed below can be used to resolve this issue.

1. Rename `styles.css` to `styles.scss` and set its content to `@import './app-theme';`
2. In `angular-cli.json`, change `styles: ["styles.css"]` to `styles: ["styles.scss"]`
3. Restart npm

Comment: restart 'npm' mean 'ng serve' or something else?

Comment: Any change in `angular-cli.json` require stop and start the service. For me the best and clean solution is only add the `custom.scss` entry in styles list and avoid to try to import inside `styles.css`.

Answer (score 22):

#### Angular 6+ --- Get all in one command

In `Angular 6+`, you simply need to install `angular-material` like

```
ng add @angular/material
```

What this command does? well see here

1. Installs `angular material`, `cdk`, `animations`
2. Adds references to the `app.module.ts`
3. Adds `material-icons'` reference to the `index.html`
4. It asks you to select the theme of your choice and adds reference to the `angular.json` (if theme does not work, import it in `styles.css/styles.scss` as described below)

but in previous versions, you were doing these steps manually

#### Angular 5

Using `Angular5+`, one or both `import` methods will work for you

```
@import "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";

@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"; // in official docs
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

1. Change your theme file name to `_app-theme.scss`
2. Change your styles.css to `styles.scss`
3. Import your theme into the styles.scss file like:

> @import './path/to/your/theme/app-theme';  // You dont need the
>   underscore and file extention here

4. You dont need to include your theme file in angular-cli.json styles: []

Comment: addition: when you rename styles.css to styles.scss, also edit angular.json 
 
    "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
     ],

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure, that you have installed angular materials in this project ? Sometimes you can copy only the content of web page, but without node_modules folder and in that case compiler can't find the path 'node_modules/@angular/material/theming'.

Just try this command and you will see.

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
```

It could help.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official guide you provided, you should not be importing your theme file into your styles.css file, instead, you should put it into the styles array of your angular-cli.json file, it should be something close to this:

```
styles: [
  "app-theme.scss",
  "styles.css"
]
```

Comment: If I do that I get "Could not find Angular Material core theme." and a broken view

Comment: Have you installed @angular/material? npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk

Comment: Yes, I can use the prebuilt themes and components like e.g. MdButton without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check this path
   ERROR in `./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css`
   while you install any other module or library. In my case I installed Angular Syncfusion scheduler
2. A new import statement gets added in the above path so what you have to do is just cut paste that import statement in `style.css` because it should it generally be there
3. And while doing this process, the Angular material folder or Angular Syncfusion folder may also get deleted from `node_modules`, so make sure you type the command `npm install` so that npm can install all the dependencies mentioned in `package.json`