# Angular Material stop working after moving projects into one main projet

Tags: angular, angular-material

I was using Angular 11 with Angular Material 11.
I group multiple angular project into one. All of those projects are working. Now, we are using Angular 9 with Angular Material 9.

We only change the structure, but the code is the same (the app.module.ts is also the same). It's just that package are manage by the main project and not my own only.

But there is a problem with this fusion. It's with the dialog which was :

[image]

And know is :

[image]

which is a little bit different.

Parts of my app.module.ts :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DialogOverviewDialogComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [DialogOverviewDialogComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} },
    { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} },
    { provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: { appearance: 'fill' } }
  ]
})
```

And the package.json :

```json
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng projects/AProject/e2e",
    "prod": "ng build --prod --aot --verbose",
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "compressorjs": "^1.0.6",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ng2-completer": "^3.0.3",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^5.3.0",
    "ngx-extended-pdf-viewer": "^6.2.0-alpha.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.901.13",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
    "@types/mocha": "^8.2.0",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^5.2.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "ng-packagr": "^9.0.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

I tried :

- Remove others projects (to see if it was a conflict)
- Edit version of dependencies, but even with exactly same version, the bug was already here
- Add multiple others import of modules
- Any error in console or at startup
- NPM install then restart

Comment: coud you provide the `package.json` file? You can also try deleting the `node_modules` folder and trying to `npm intall` it again from scratch

Comment: Sure, I just add it in main post. For the deletion of node_modules, I'm currently trying to do it but it's long.

Comment: Update: Nothing change after deleting `node_modules` and run `npm install`

Comment: The angular material classes may have change when you downgraded the dependency, I suggest you to https://v9.material.angular.io/ check this documentation, and to check if your code is correct.

Comment: I followed the tutorial, such as I get issues while adding material, I reinstall it and then import the CSS.
Now, it works fine (I post an answer). Thanks u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.

The CSS file was buggy, and after a Material reinstall and [importation of angular material's css](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48315206/10952503), it works fine.