# Angular material can't find stylesheed

Tags: angular, angular-material

I created new angular project and I am using Angular 17.0.10 and I am trying to apply custom theming based on the documentation, I have added the following code in my styles.scss

```
   /* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */

html, body { height: 100%; }
body { margin: 0; font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif; }

@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@include mat-core();

$candy-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$candy-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);
$candy-app-theme:   mat-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $candy-app-primary,
    accent: $candy-app-accent,
  )
));

@include angular-material-theme($candy-app-theme);


// Define an alternate dark theme.
$dark-primary: mat-palette($mat-blue-grey);
$dark-accent:  mat-palette($mat-amber, A200, A100, A400);
$dark-warn:    mat-palette($mat-deep-orange);
$dark-theme:   mat-dark-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $dark-primary,
    accent: $dark-accent,
    warn: $dark-warn,
  )
));

.unicorn-dark-theme {
  @include angular-material-color($dark-theme);
}
```

I get error:

Can't find stylesheet to import

```
ng serve
```

⠸ Building...
X [ERROR] Can't find stylesheet to import.
╷
5 │ @import '~@angular/material/theming';
│         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
src\styles.scss 5:9  root stylesheet [plugin angular-sass]

```
angular:styles/global:styles:2:8:
  2 │ @import 'src/styles.scss';
    ╵         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Application bundle generation failed. [12.132 seconds]
Watch mode enabled. Watching for file changes...

I have followed the instructions posted here: [Angular Material - Can't resolve '@angular/material/theming'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45524827/angular-material-cant-resolve-angular-material-theming) it also didn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

For angular material 17, I think the imports are a bit different, you can create a `theme.scss` and import like below!

[Angular material theming stackblitz](https://v13.material.angular.io/guide/theming#custom-themes-with-sass)

```
// Custom Theming for Angular Material
// For more information: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
// Plus imports for other components in your app.

// Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
// Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!
@include mat.core();

// Define the palettes for your theme using the Material Design palettes available in palette.scss
// (imported above). For each palette, you can optionally specify a default, lighter, and darker
// hue. Available color palettes: https://material.io/design/color/
$theme-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$indigo-palette);
$theme-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$pink-palette, A200, A100, A400);

// The warn palette is optional (defaults to red).
$theme-warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette);

// Create the theme object. A theme consists of configurations for individual
// theming systems such as "color" or "typography".
$theme: mat.define-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $theme-primary,
    accent: $theme-accent,
    warn: $theme-warn,
  ),
  typography: mat.define-typography-config(),
));

// Include theme styles for core and each component used in your app.
// Alternatively, you can import and @include the theme mixins for each component
// that you are using.
@include mat.all-component-themes($theme);
```

[reference stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Ftheme.scss)